# Enforcing cross table uniqueness of records in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  adata         varchar(255),

  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
  );

CREATE TABLE B (
  id            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bdata         varchar(255),
  a_id          int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );

CREATE TABLE C (
  id            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cdata         varchar(255),
  b_id          int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Elements of `C` (associated with `B`'s) must be unique only for a given `A`. I.e., the combination of (`cdata` and `b_id.a_id`) must be unique.

I realize that I could add another column (pointing to `A`) to the `C` table and create a unique key. Is there any way to enforce uniqueness without adding another column to `C`?